# Правильная архитектура Laravel-приложения при большом кол-ве вводных данных

Tags: php, laravel, архитектура

Всем привет. Пишу CRM-систему на Laravel, впервые сталкиваюсь с валидацией большого количества данных. Столкнулся с проблемой при добавлении нового заказа в CRM.

Что необходимо проверять перед добавлением нового заказа:

- Номер телефона. Понятно, что валидацию номера добавляем в `StoreOrderRequest`.
- Есть ли такой клиент в базе (поиск по номеру). Понятно, что делается `Customer::findOrNew()`.
- Доступен ли в данный момент товар для заказа
- Указан ли адрес доставки (если да, то еще нужно добавить задачу уточнить адрес доставки)

И так далее. Список довольно большой, он будет расширяться по мере разрастания функционала. Но пока что не понимаю, именно с идеологической стороны Laravel, куда именно мне следует запихнуть всю валидацию данных? Понятно, что именно входные данные (Имя клиента, телефон клиента) проверяем в `StoreOrderRequest`, но куда лучше вынести всю бизнес-логику, как это реализуется?

Есть `OrderController`, есть `public function create(StoreOrderRequest $request){}`, но ведь делать контроллер толстым не есть хорошо.

Насколько правильным будет сделать `Event` нового заказа, а такие параметры, как проверка на ввод адреса доставки, вынести в отдельный `Listener` и реализовывать бизнес-логику, связанную именно с данным параметром, именно в данном "слушателе"?

Хочется узнать мнение более опытных разработчиков, интересует именно архитектура в данном случае.

Comment: `Идеологически`, Laravel хочет чтобы вы проводили валидацию в `Контроллере`. НО, реалии таковы, что такой подход влияет на масштабируемость в худшую сторону, поэтому обычно валидацию проводят в `моделях`.

Comment: Вся бизнес логика сидит в моделях, что касается валидации, вам нужно создавать **request** и там валидировать большинство входных данных, что касается остальной работы, ее стоит валидировать уже в самой модели. Я думаю основную работу вы сможете проверить именно в реквестах, львиная доля будет сидеть именно там, а уж остальная часть, сугубо узкой направленности будет проверяться именно в модели, ну и сохраняться там же.

Answer (score 1):

У вас будет широкая, многосторонняя валидация, поэтому её нужно будет выполнять в классе запроса StoreOrderRequest при его парсинге из данных формы. К примеру, создаете объект запроса и передаете ему данные формы в конструкторе, и потом вызывая его validate функцию.

После этого получаете заполненные значения его свойств-моделей которые вам нужны. Это всё можно обернуть своей функцией (parse, к примеру), которая возвращает список ошибок, либо в их отсутствии заполняет свойства-модели из данных форм. После этого можно будет делать проверку у этих свойств-моделей.

Насчет сообщений могу сказать что они созданы для работы независимых частей/модулей проекта, а не для непосредственной обработки, необходимой в логике контроллера или класса запроса. Если исполняемая работа асинхронна то вы выиграете используя их (но это опять же только в том случае если сообщения тоже на самом деле асинхронны, т.е. работают в отдельном процессе, вне процесса контекста запроса).

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно мыслите на тему того, чтобы сохранить контроллер тонким. Следуя хорошим практикам проектирования Laravel приложений, следует делать толстые модели и тонкие контроллеры.

При этом собственно бизнес логику приложения, т.е. следование процессам обработки заказа и т.п. можно вынести в отдельный сервис, к которому можно будет обращаться из любого контроллера.

Различного рода уведомления и т.п. можно вынести в некоторый универсальный NotificationsListener и генерировать для него события на отправку сообщений.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте сервисный слой OrderService.php всю бизнес логику выносите туда

```
$this->orderService->checkOrder($order);
```

- метод будет проверять доступен ли заказ в данный момент. Контроллер при этом остается чистым и бизнес логика доступна в любом месте.

А сам orderService.php должен обращаться к 
orderRepository.php - если нужно что-то сделать с БД
event - если нужно какое-то событие.